# How to convert a dictionary according to a json scheme, Python3

Tags: python-3.x, jsonschema

I have a json scheme, which specifies the format of a dictionary in Python 3.

```
INPUT_SCHEME = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "a1": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "a1_1": {"type": ["string", "null"]},
                "a1_2": {"type": ["number", "null"]},
            },
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "minProperties": 2,
        },
        "a2": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {"type": ["number", "null"]},
        },
        "a3": {
            "type": ["number", "null"],
        },
        "a4": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "a4_1": {"type": ["string", "null"]},
                "a4_2": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "a4_2_1": {"type": ["string", "null"]},
                        "a4_2_2": {"type": ["number", "null"]},
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": False,
                    "minProperties": 2,
                },
            },
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "minProperties": 2,
        },
        "a5": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "a5_1": {"type": ["string", "null"]},
                    "a5_2": {"type": ["number", "null"]},
                },
                "additionalProperties": False,
                "minProperties": 2,
            },
        },
    },
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "minProperties": 5,
}
```

And I want to write a function which can convert an arbitrary input dictionary to the format defined by the `INPUT_SCHEME`.

The rules are:

1. if the input dict misses a filed, then fill the filed with None or empty list in the output dict.
2. if the input dict has a key that is not defined in the `INPUT_SCHEME`, then remove it in the output dict.

For example, suppose I have `a_input`, where only `'a1'` is correct. `'a2', 'a3', and 'a4'` are missing. Each element in `'a5'` misses one property. And `'a6'` is an un-defined field.
The function I want to write should convert `a_input` to `a_output`. And you can use `jsonschema.validate` to check.

```
a_input = {
    'a1': {'a1_1': 'apple', 'a1_2': 20.5},
    'a5': [{'a5_1': 'pear'}, {'a5_2': 18.5}],
    'a6': [1, 2, 3, 4],
}

a_output = {
    'a1': {'a1_1': 'apple', 'a1_2': 20.5},
    'a2': [],
    'a3': None,
    'a4': {
        'a4_1': None,
        'a4_2': {
            'a4_2_1': None,
            'a4_2_2': None,
        }
    },
    'a5': [
        {
            'a5_1': 'pear',
            'a5_2': None,
        },
        {
            'a5_1': None,
            'a5_2': 18.5,
        }
    ]
}

jsonschema.validate(a_output, schema=INPUT_SCHEME)
```

I tried to write the function, but could not make it. Mainly because there are too many `if-else` check plus the nested structure, and I got lost. Could you please help me?

Thanks.

```
def my_func(a_from):
    a_to = dict()
    for key_1 in INPUT_SCHEME['properties'].keys():
        if key_1 not in a_from:
            a_to[key_1] = None  # This is incorrect, since the structure of a_to[key_1] depends on INPUT_SCHEME.
            continue

        layer_1 = INPUT_SCHEME['properties'][key_1]
        if 'properties' in layer_1:  # like a1, a4
            for key_2 in layer_1['properties'].keys():
                layer_2 = layer_1['properties'][key_2]
                ...

                # but it can be a nest of layers. Like a4, there are 3 layers. In real case, it can have more layers.

        elif 'items' in layer_1:
            if 'properties' in layer_1['items']:  # like a5
                ...
            else:  # like a2
                ...
        else:  # like 3
            ...
    return a_to
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive algorithm suits this.

I divided it into 2 different functions as removing undefined properties and filling non-existent ones from the schema are 2 different tasks. You can merge them into one if you wish.

For filling nonexistent properties, I just create arrays, objects and `None`s, and then recurse inwards.

For removing the undefined properties, I compare the schema keys and remove unmatched keys, again, recursing inwards.

You may see comments and type checks in code:

```
def fill_nonexistent_properties(input_dictionary, schema):
    """
    Fill missing properties in input_dictionary according to the schema.
    """
    properties = schema['properties']
    missing_properties = set(properties).difference(input_dictionary)

    # Fill all missing properties.
    for key in missing_properties:
        value = properties[key]
        if value['type'] == 'array':
            input_dictionary[key] = []
        elif value['type'] == 'object':
            input_dictionary[key] = {}
        else:
            input_dictionary[key] = None
    
    # Recurse inside all properties.
    for key, value in properties.items():
        
        # If it's an array of objects, recurse inside each item.
        if value['type'] == 'array' and value['items']['type'] == 'object':
            object_list = input_dictionary[key]

            if not isinstance(object_list, list):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not a list.")

            for item in object_list:
                if not isinstance(item, dict):
                    raise ValueError(
                        f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not a list of objects.")
                fill_nonexistent_properties(item, value['items'])

        # If it's an object, recurse inside it.
        elif value['type'] == 'object':
            obj = input_dictionary[key]
            if not isinstance(obj, dict):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not a dictionary.")
            fill_nonexistent_properties(obj, value)

def remove_undefined_properties(input_dictionary, schema):
    """
    Remove properties in input_dictionary that are not defined in the schema.
    """
    properties = schema['properties']
    undefined_properties = set(input_dictionary).difference(properties)

    # Remove all undefined properties.
    for key in undefined_properties:
        del input_dictionary[key]
    
    # Recurse inside all existing sproperties.
    for key, value in input_dictionary.items():
        property_shcema = properties[key]

        # If it's an array of objects, recurse inside each item.
        if isinstance(value, list):
            if not property_shcema['type'] == 'array':
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not a list.")

            # We're only dealing with objects inside arrays.
            if not property_shcema['items']['type'] == 'object':
                continue
            
            for item in value:
                # Make sure each item is an object.
                if not isinstance(item, dict):
                    raise ValueError(
                        f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not a list of objects.")
                remove_undefined_properties(item, property_shcema['items'])
        
        # If it's an object, recurse inside it.
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            # Make sure the object is supposed to be an object.
            if not property_shcema['type'] == 'object':
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not an object.")

            remove_undefined_properties(value, property_shcema)


import pprint
pprint.pprint(a_input)
fill_nonexistent_properties(a_input, INPUT_SCHEME)
remove_undefined_properties(a_input, INPUT_SCHEME)
print("-"*10, "OUTPUT", "-"*10)
pprint.pprint(a_input)
```

Output:

```
{'a1': {'a1_1': 'apple', 'a1_2': 20.5},
 'a5': [{'a5_1': 'pear'}, {'a5_2': 18.5}],
 'a6': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
---------- OUTPUT ----------
{'a1': {'a1_1': 'apple', 'a1_2': 20.5},
 'a2': [],
 'a3': None,
 'a4': {'a4_1': None, 'a4_2': {'a4_2_1': None, 'a4_2_2': None}},
 'a5': [{'a5_1': 'pear', 'a5_2': None}, {'a5_1': None, 'a5_2': 18.5}]}
```

Comment: thanks for this elegant solution! The idea of recursive prevents the large amount of `if-else` blocks and `set().difference()` save tens of lines.

Comment: @aura I typically do not answer these types of questions as they almost always lack data or specifications. Your question however was very detailed, showed effort and contained all of the necessary information including input, output, schema, full comprehensive explanation, and the best of all - an example with edge cases. Showing the possible edge cases in your example was extremely important and was the only way for me to test my code. I do not know your level of programming, but this was a professional way of asking a question, well done.

Comment: Hey Bharel, 
I am facing an issue. For a property like "a5" in the question, the fill_nonexistent_properties method appends the same keys multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the excellent answer that @Bharel give us, I need to add some improvements to work for me.

I would use this in conjunction with SQLAlchemy, so some parts like the checks `if isinstance(item, Base):` is specific for SQLAlchemy, which checks if the object is an instance of some SQLAlchemy declarative base.

```
from logging import getLogger

from api.models import Base

logger = getLogger(__name__)

def remove_undefined_properties(input_dictionary, schema):
    """
    Remove properties in input_dictionary that are not defined in the schema.
    """

    if isinstance(input_dictionary, Base):
        input_dictionary = input_dictionary.asdict()

    properties = schema['properties']
    logger.debug('Properties "%s"', properties)
    logger.debug('Dict "%s"', input_dictionary)

    undefined_properties = set(input_dictionary).difference(properties)

    if undefined_properties:
        logger.debug('Removendo key(s) %s baseado no schema', undefined_properties)

    # Remove all undefined properties.
    for key in undefined_properties:
        del input_dictionary[key]
    
    # Recurse inside all existing properties.
    for key, value in input_dictionary.items():
        property_schema = properties[key]

        # If it's an array of objects, recurse inside each item.
        if isinstance(value, list):
            if not property_schema['type'] == 'array':
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not a list.")

            # We're only dealing with objects inside arrays.
            if not property_schema['items']['type'] == 'object':
                continue
            
            input_dictionary[key] = []

            for item in value:
                # Make sure each item is an object.

                if not isinstance(item, dict):
                    
                    if isinstance(item, Base):
                        item = item.asdict()
                    else:
                        raise ValueError(
                            f"Invalid JSON object: {key} não é uma lista de objetos válida, " \
                            f"os itens dentro da lista são do tipo {type(item)}")
                
                input_dictionary[key].append(remove_undefined_properties(item, property_schema['items']))

        # If it's an object, recurse inside it.
        elif isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, Base):
            # Make sure the object is supposed to be an object.
            if not property_schema['type'] == 'object':
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Invalid JSON object: {key} is not an object.")
            
            input_dictionary[key] = remove_undefined_properties(value, property_schema)

    return input_dictionary

def match_schema(dict: dict, schema: dict):
    
    remove_undefined_properties(dict, schema)

    return dict
```

Please note that in my context, all the calls to `.asdict()` method is for converting my SQLAlchemy models to dict.

Apart from that, the main diff with the @Bharel answer is the `input_dictionary[key].append(remove_undefined_properties(item, property_schema['items']))` and `input_dictionary[key] = remove_undefined_properties(value, property_schema)`. Aparrently the recursion only works in that way, at least in my case.